# remove last part with cloudformation syntax

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I got an arn reference with `Fn::GetAtt: [ logGroup, Arn ]`

```
arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:123456789012:log-group:/log-group-1234:*
```

but i need:

```
arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:123456789012:log-group:/log-group-1234
```

So the last part (*) need be removed.

How can I use the reference to archive it? I can split and select the last session, but how to remove it? (**I hard code the log group name as sample only**)

> { "Fn::Select" : [ "8", { "Fn::Split": [":", {"Fn::ImportValue": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:123456789012:log-group:/log-group-1234:*"}]}] }

#### Update:

Thanks, @Miles. I made it work

```
    Fn::Select:
      - '0'
      - Fn::Split:
        - ":*"
        - Fn::GetAtt: [ LogsGroup, Arn ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to split by more than one character. Try:

```
{  
   "Fn::Select":[  
      "0",
      {  
         "Fn::Split":[  
            ":*",
            {  
               "Fn::ImportValue":"arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:123456789012:log-group:/log-group-1234:*"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Just as a side note, it doesn't make much sense to use `ImportValue` like that, but I guess you provided this just as a placeholder.